# How do I install Cario 1.16.0 for WeasyPrint 51 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, apt, cairo, dpkg, package-management

I need Cario > 1.15.4 to get weasyprint 51 working (https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html), but the docs seem to think it as simple as running:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python3-dev python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-wheel python3-cffi libcairo2 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libffi-dev shared-mime-info
```

...for an Ubuntu install. But this gives me:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcairo2 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.29) but 2.24-11+deb9u4 is to be installed
             Depends: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.12.6) but 2.11.0-6.7+b1 is to be installed
             Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.9.1) but 2.6.3-3.2 is to be installed
 python3-cffi : Depends: python3-cffi-backend (< 1.9.1-2+c) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: python3-cffi-backend (>= 1.9.1-2) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: python3-pycparser but it is not going to be installed
 python3-dev : Depends: libpython3-dev (= 3.5.3-1) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3.5-dev (>= 3.5.3-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 python3-pip : Depends: python-pip-whl (= 9.0.1-2+deb9u1) but it is not going to be installed
 python3-setuptools : Depends: python3-pkg-resources (= 33.1.1-1) but it is not going to be installed
```

So I tried `apt -f install` and then ran the command again. Everything when fine but `apt list | grep libcairo2` still shows:

```
libcairo2/oldstable,now 1.14.8-1 amd64 [installed]
libcairo2-dev/oldstable 1.14.8-1 amd64
libcairo2-doc/oldstable 1.14.8-1 all
```

So I tried `apt install libcairo2-dev` but I get:

```
root@f8657d732ac8:~# apt list | grep cairo
...
libcairo2/now 1.14.8-1 amd64 [installed,local]
libcairo2-dev/now 1.14.8-1 amd64 [installed,local]
...
```

I also tried:

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cairo/libcairo2_1.16.0-4_amd64.deb
dpkg -i libcairo2_1.16.0-4_amd64.deb
```

but then I get:

```
root@54e69efbb962:~# dpkg -i libcairo2_1.16.0-4_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 30555 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libcairo2_1.16.0-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcairo2:amd64 (1.16.0-4) over (1.14.8-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcairo2:amd64:
 libcairo2:amd64 depends on libc6 (>= 2.29); however:
  Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.24-11+deb9u4.
 libcairo2:amd64 depends on libfontconfig1 (>= 2.12.6); however:
  Version of libfontconfig1:amd64 on system is 2.11.0-6.7+b1.
 libcairo2:amd64 depends on libfreetype6 (>= 2.9.1); however:
  Version of libfreetype6:amd64 on system is 2.6.3-3.2.

dpkg: error processing package libcairo2:amd64 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libcairo2:amd64
root@54e69efbb962:~#
```

If I run `apt --fix-broken install` to fix broken dependencies and run  `dpkg -i libcairo2_1.16.0-4_amd64.deb` I get the same result.
I have also tried `apt install ./libcairo2_1.16.0-4_amd64.deb` and that gives me:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcairo2 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.29) but 2.24-11+deb9u4 is installed
             Depends: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.12.6) but 2.11.0-6.7+b1 is installed
             Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.9.1) but 2.6.3-3.2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried installing the packages on a new ubuntu 18.04 docker image and it went smoothly. Below are the steps I did:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y lsb-release && apt-get clean all
apt-get install build-essential python3-dev python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-wheel python3-cffi libcairo2 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libffi-dev shared-mime-info
pip3 install weasyprint
```

[image: weasyprint]

I uploaded the container image on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/layers/jegtugado/public/weasyprint/images/sha256-9a294b5f5b7f57230b4efc20961bd5a0aeed6870babef8d2460e9ea833384e5f?context=explore).

```
docker pull jegtugado/public:weasyprint
```